# String splitting then pushing to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I'm trying to split my string from an array into separate words then push them into a new array to print them out from that array as separate words. How do I do that? What I have so far is down below, but I think I have my methods called in the function in the wrong order.

```
var myArray = ["John Doe", "johnDoe"];
var cutName = function(x) {
    var cutArray = [];
    cutArray.push(x.split());
    return cutArray;
};
print cutName(myArray[0]);
```

How can I improve my code?

Comment: Why do you need to push them onto another array? Why not just return `x.split()`?

Comment: Could you please show the result, that you expected of your code?

Comment: @dognose Code Review should only be used with correct code.

Comment: @Barmar i did not check if the code is working. But theres is no *clear* problem outlined, just asking for improvement.

Comment: @dognose Then vote to close as *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior...* and please read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @dognose Yeah, he wants it improved from not working to working.

Comment: @Barmar: Yeah I see. However from the post I cannot derive that it's not working. So I assumed it working, but OP seeking for a more efficent way, than needing to call `cutName` multiple times. However, I will keep this in mind before recommending codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @dognose I'm not sure if `print` does anything in JS, as it isn't a reserved word based on [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp), so the code wasn't working to begin with.

Comment: As I wrote: *I will keep this in mind before recommending codreview again*. I'm feeling sorry for any inconveniences caused. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you meant to do was split the elements in your array based on white space separating them, and you forgot to add the `" "` argument to your `split()`

```js
var myArray = ["John Doe", "johnDoe"];
var cutName = function(x) {
  var cutArray = x.split(" "); //place demimeter here

  return cutArray;
};
var arr = cutName(myArray[0]);

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
  alert(arr[i]);
}
```

This will split your original argument to `cutName`, the first element in `myArray` `"John Doe"`, and turn it into an array, with the elements being anything separated by a single white space. It will then loop through and print out each element in the new array.

Input: `myArray[0]` -> `"John Doe"`

Turns into: `["John", "Doe"]`

output:
Line 1: `John`

Line 2: `Doe`

Comment: Thank you, Abdul. I still have a hard time being precise about how I want to ask my question or where I gotten lost in what I just learned, but you've hit the nail right on the head. That was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You end up returning an array within an array, which probably isn't what you're expecting.

The result of `x.split()` *is already* an array (e.g. `['John', 'Doe']`), then you push it into `cutArray`, ending up with `[['John', 'Doe']]`, which is probably why you're confused. **Note**: omitting the `separator` parameter to `split()` will return an array where the only element is the original string -- which might be contributing to your unexpected results).

Your `cutName` function is a long way of simply calling `x.split(' ')`. Your code could be shortened to:

```
console.log(myArray[0].split(' '));
```

Without showing us expected output, I'm not sure what else you wanted your code to do.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you, assuming you want to split each element of array and consolidate all the split parts into a larger array.

```
var myArray = ["John Doe", "johnDoe"];
var newArray = (myArray.map(function(x) {return x.split(' ')})).join().split(",");
console.log(newArray);
```

**Output**

```
[ 'John', 'Doe', 'johnDoe' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are after, but this might work for you:

```
var separateWords = myArray.map(function(word) {
    return word.split(' '); // note the empty space
});

// output [ [ 'John', 'Doe' ], [ 'johnDoe' ] ]
```

Also, to get it in a single array:

```
separateWords = separateWords.reduce(function(a,b) { 
  return a.concat(b); 
})

// output [ 'John', 'Doe', 'johnDoe' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

the split function needs a delimiter showing by which character should the string be splited. So your code should be:

```
var myArray = ["John Doe", "johnDoe"];
var cutName = function(x) {
    var cutArray = [];
    cutArray.push(x.split(""));
    return cutArray;
};
document.body.innerHTML=cutName(myArray[0]);
```